# Checking if a number is negative and using absolute value in Racket

Tags: racket, absolute-value

I want to check if x is negative, and if it is, get the absolute value of it. Otherwise, do nothing.
Here is what I've tried so far.

```
(when (< x 0)
  (set! x (abs x))
  )
```

```
(set! x(abs x))
```

Both of these gave a "contract violation. Expected: real? Given: #f"

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried this and I think I've made progress.

```
(cond
  [(< x 0) (set! y(abs x))]
  [else (print "input error")]
  )
```

The '< x 0' is having a hard time comparing 0 to a float. How do I compare floats?

Comment: At first you want to set `x` to the absolute value of `x`. In your edited code, you use `y` for the absolute value of `x`. Which is right now? The same variable or another?

Comment: What if you write '< x 0.0'? Does this will help with your float problem?

Comment: Yup that did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not only write

`(set! x(abs x))`

? It will work for negative and positive values.